# AIX - How to kill using process name instead of PID

Tags: process, aix, kill

Is there a way to kill a process by specifying the process name instead of PID for AIX?
E.g. for the below process I want to kill it by specifying `sapstartsrv` instead of `10682424`

```
hmsadm 10682424        1   0   Apr 30      -  0:54 /usr/sap/HMS/ASCS01/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/HMS/SYS/profile/START_ASCS01_H\
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you determinate which `sapstartsrv` to kill?

Comment: I just need to kill any remaining sapstartsrv processes. The reason why I want to kill using process name is I want to automate the process as if to kill with PID, I first need to determine the PID and then run the kill as a second step. 

Is there a script that can automate this - first grep the PID and then kill the relevant PID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command like this:

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef|grep sapstartsrv|awk '{print $2}')
```

of course first check if command `ps -ef|grep sapstartsrv|awk '{print $2}'` return only processes you want to kill

Comment: I tried with sapstartsrv but still getting variable syntax error for the kill command. Any idea?

Comment: @userguy, please edit your question and add there what you execute and what error you get

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The brackets around the first letter of process you are trying to kill helps. Obviously change this to a valid server.

`while true; do date; ping -c4 server; sleep 500; done &`

`ps -aef | grep -i [p]ing | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

If that doesn't work sometimes you have to kill the parent process.

`ps -aef | grep -i [p]ing | awk '{print $2 " " $3}' | xargs kill -9`